# combine multiple column output in kubectl using custom-columns or jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, formatting, kubectl

This is the output with `custom-columns`

```
$ kubectl -n web get pod -ocustom-columns="Name:.metadata.name,Image:.spec.containers[0].image"
Name      Image
mysql-0   myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
mysql-1   myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
mysql-2   myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
```

This is the output with `jsonpath` for single pod

```
$ kubectl -n web get pod -o jsonpath="{..metadata.name}:{..spec.containers[0].image}" mysql-0
mysql-0:myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
```

This is the output with `jsonpath` for multiple pods

```
$ kubectl -n web get pod -o jsonpath="{..metadata.name}:{..spec.containers[0].image}"
mysql-0 mysql-1 mysql-2:myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7 myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7 myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
```

Now how to combine this into a single column or word, something like this, using `-ocustom-columns` or `-ojsonpath`

```
mysql-0=myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
mysql-1=myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
mysql-2=myrepo.mydomain.com/mysql:5.7
```

Comment: Hello @Logu. It can't be done with `kubectl` solely. Could you please try this command: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -ocustom-columns="Name:.metadata.name,Image:.spec.containers[0].image" | awk '{ print $1,"=",$2 }' | sed 's/\s//g' | tail +2`?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor not yet. Have to try the jsonpath with range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using kubectl using plain `jsonpath`:

```
kubectl get pod -n <namespace> -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}={.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Example:

```
kubectl get pod -n default -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}={.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'
nginx-0=nginx
nginx-1=nginx
nginx-2=nginx
```

Here `range` feature is used to loop over all the pods:

```
{range items[*]} ...<LOGIC HERE>... {end}
```

Between the range block(As described above), use the `jsonpath`, notice the `=` sign is used as per our requirement.

```
{.metadata.name}={.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}
```